# Android Save permission for a USB device across detach, re-attach

Tags: android, permissions, usb

Struggling a bit with Android >=10's UsbDevice class and detecting re-attachment of the same USB device. Prior to Android 10, I could use UsbDevice.getSerialNumber to get a unique handle for a USB device (if it had one). UsbDevice.getDeviceName tends to change from attach to attach e.g. /dev/bus/usb/001/002, /dev/bus/usb/001/003. For Android >=10 you need to ask for user USB permission before calling getSerialNumber. Without having a manifest intent filter for the USB device type and saving the App as the preferred client this is now very messy - a new Permission Request dialogue is needed for each re-attach. Has anyone found a workaround for this? USB OTG connectors are not the most secure so yank then re-plug is a reasonable thing to want to do.

Comment: Unless there are multiple USB devices using the same USB chip, why not use the standard **UsbDevice.getVendorId()** and **UsbDevice.getProductId()** to uniquely identify the USB device instead of the permissive **UsbDevice.getSerialNumber()** since API 29?

Comment: Anyway, setting the required USB permissions is simple... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host

Comment: my use case was for two different instances of the same type of device